# Disable anonymous user cookie with Django

Tags: django, session, cookies, anonymous

I use django auth for my website, which needs to have the session middleware installed.

Django session middleware always adds a session cookie, even for anonymous users (users that are not authenticated). When they authenticate the cookie is replaced by another one indicating the user is logged-in.

I want to disable the anonymous user cookie for caching purposes (varnish).

Is there a way to disable anonymous user cookies without removing session middleware which is necessary for apps using auth?

Comment: The session is not created if you don't access or modify it in your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Session data is set in the cookie in the `process_response` of `SessionMiddleware`. This function doesn't use any setting or `request.user`, so you do not have any way of knowing inside this method whether the user is a logged in user or an anonymous user. So, you can't disable sending the session cookie to the browser.

However if you want this functionality then you can subclass `SessionMiddleware` and overide `process_response`.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.conf import settings

class NewSessionMiddleware(SessionMiddleware):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response = super(NewSessionMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response)
        #You have access to request.user in this method
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            del response.cookies[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]
        return response
```

And you can use your `NewSessionMiddleware` in place of `SessionMiddleware`.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'myapp.middleware.NewSessionMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: I thought about subclassing but is request.user.is_authenticated() hit the db for this kind of check ?if yes this mean it will hit the DB each time a page is loaded ?

Comment: No `is_authenticated()` doesn't hit the db. Populating `request.user` hits the db and it is done by AuthenticationMiddleware. But this you anyways want to happen on all requests. But `is_authenticated` only returns either True or False depending on the user, to be specific if `request.user` is an instance of `User`, it will return True and if `request.user` is an instance of `AnonymousUser`, it will return False. But it will not hit the db.

Comment: This works, but it's better to use response.delete_cookie(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME) instead of the 'del' keyword.

Comment: I just tested this and `del` actually works better because it will leave out the cookie, not just set it empty like so: `Set-Cookie: sessionid=; expires=...`, which is what I get with `response.delete_cookie` method (on my version of Django).