# Clarity: Django user cookie exists after logout

Tags: python, django

I noticed in Chrome web tools that even after i log out of my Django site, the user cookie still exists. Im assuming this is the anon user? There is not much in the django documentation about anon users. is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After logging out, your session cookie is destroyed and its place is taken by anonymous session cookie. When you log back in again, this anonymous session cookie is replaced by your session cookie.

You don't really have to worry about it. However if you really want to disable that cookie, take a look at the following resources:

1. [This question on StackOverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069753/disable-anonymous-user-cookie-with-django).
2. [Django-cookieless](http://github.com/edcrewe/django-cookieless) project on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying wanted to make sure It wasn't something I'd done