# With @csrf_exempt still have Set-Cookie: csrftoken

Tags: django, cookies

With Django 1.8, I do not want to have a cookie set on the homepage of my site when the users are not logged in. So I decorate my view with @csrf_exempt like

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt 
def mainhome(request):
```

When I look at the query I can see the cookie still set, why ?

```
rodo@roz-desktop:~/(master)$ curl  -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 13 Jun 2015 08:59:27 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Cookie
X-QueryInspect-Duplicate-SQL-Queries: 2
X-QueryInspect-Total-SQL-Time: 34 ms
X-QueryInspect-Total-Request-Time: 283 ms
X-QueryInspect-Num-SQL-Queries: 3
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=sa5x0DyxgBamca0D84ZZnzl2WAL0evkv; expires=Sat, 11-Jun-2016 08:59:27 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Daniel Roseman indicated, `@csrf_exempt` will not help you with that.

The middleware responsible for the session cookie is `SessionMiddleware`. You can read more about it in the [Django Docs: How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/). Unfortunately, there is no similar decorator in order to exempt some specific view.

So in order to customize the middleware's behaviour, you would need to inherit from `SessionMiddleware`. There is a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069753/disable-anonymous-user-cookie-with-django) on the matter on SO.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it does exactly what I was looking for, the nice answer is really nice, shame that I hace not found it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

`csrf_exempt` controls whether or not CSRF is enforced on POST. It has nothing to do with whether or not the CSRF cookie is set; that is done by the CsrfViewMiddleware for all responses.