# How to disable cookies in Django manually

Tags: python, django, cookies

I know that there are apps for Django to handle cookies, but I want to do it manually. I have a Django application with only two cookies: `csrftoken` and `sessionid`.

I want to add a cookie consent banner where the user can block all cookies. How can I do that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069753/disable-anonymous-user-cookie-with-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import `@csrf_extempt` from django.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

To have a view not use csrf tokens do this. (Note: you have to do this for each view that won't have csrf tokens)

```
@csrf_exempt
def viewGoesHere(request):
    pass
```

And to disable the session cookies you need to replace the middleware. (The thing that makes cookies work). So put this code in there as the code itself.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.conf import settings

class NewSessionMiddleware(SessionMiddleware):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response = super(NewSessionMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response)
        # You have access to request.user in this method
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            del response.cookies[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]
        return response
```

And you need to replace `'myapp.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` with `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'myapp.middleware.NewSessionMiddleware', # This is the new middleware
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```